# To agree with someone

Tags: word-usage, verbs, phrasal-verbs

According to Cambridge Dictionary the phrasal verb [agree with someone](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/agree-with-sb) can be used in the following way:

> If a situation or new conditions agree with you, they make you feel healthy and happy: 
>   **Example:** You look well - the mountain air must agree with you.

I was wondering if I can use this verb in the scenario below:

Imagine you have an old friend who disappeared after marriage a long time ago (say one year) and was never heard of again! 
One day, you run into him out of the blue when you are walking down the street where he lived before. You immediately notice that he has put on weight and looks far more happier and healthier comparing the time he still was a single man. Can you say smilingly and as a joke:

> - Hey, it seems that marriage has agreed with you man.

If no, then why?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: I wonder for which dialect are you speaking @stevenkeiretsu?

Comment: I'm a native British English speaker.

Comment: "Must agree with you" as in the Cambridge example, or "is agreeing with you", would be more usual.

Comment: Hey, it seems marriage agrees with you. There is no need to use the present perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you worded it is good! I would probably say, “It seems marriage agrees with you, man!” But it’s the same thing ; )